# Using PowerShell in nuget package to edit Global.asax

Tags: c#, nuget-package

Using a Install.ps1 script with a Nuget Package, I'm attempting to add code to the Global.asax.cs file for customization purposes. With my Install.ps1 script the -replace command is not working. Infact I'm not able to assign any text to the variable $a I'm using with -replace and have it written to the "Global.asax.cs" file. The 3 lines of script involving -replace and the clipboard do work with "Windows PowerShell" outside of nuget. I know that the variable $a is passing along content from the clipboard since commenting out "#$customGlobalAsax.Document.Selection.Copy()" will write whatever happens to be in the clipboard into the Global.asax.cs file. 
Any Suggestions? Thanks.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$customGlobalAsax = $project.ProjectItems | ForEach-Object { $_.ProjectItems } | where { $_.Name -eq "Global.asax.cs" }
$customGlobalAsax.Open()
$customGlobalAsax.Document.Activate()
$customGlobalAsax.Document.Selection.SelectAll() 
$customGlobalAsax.Document.Selection.Copy()

$a = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetText()  
$a = $a -replace "using Company.Web.Mvc.ViewBase;","using Company.Web.Mvc.ViewBase;`r`nusing Company.Web.Address;"
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText($a)   

$customGlobalAsax.Document.Selection.Delete()
$customGlobalAsax.Document.Selection.Paste()
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use [WebActivator](http://nuget.org/packages/WebActivatorEx/) to hook into the events you want to use?

Comment: Steven, I tried WebActivator and for the purposes of the edits of the Global.asax.cs it worked ... Thanks! ..I'm still interested in modifying code files though.  I have some attributes I would like to add to existing controller methods.

Answer (score 0):

from what I can see, there is some problem with this line since it will return nothing:

```
$customGlobalAsax = $project.ProjectItems | ForEach-Object { $_.ProjectItems } | where { $_.Name -eq "Global.asax.cs" }
```

The following is my test:

```
$directory = dir *

$directory | foreach {$_.name}
```

The above run successfully.

But the following returns nothing:

```
$directory = dir *

$directory.name | foreach {$_.name}
```

I believe in the latter case $_.name represents $directory.name.name which doesn't exist.

So it seems like this line in your script

```
$customGlobalAsax = $project.ProjectItems | ForEach-Object { $_.ProjectItems } | where { $_.Name -eq "Global.asax.cs" }
```

should be changed to:

```
  $customGlobalAsax = $project | ForEach-Object { $_.ProjectItems } | where { $_.Name -eq "Global.asax.cs" }
```

Comment: Peter, I gave your suggestion a try. Unfortunately removing `.ProjectItems` removes the handle on the "Global.asas.cs" file. I tested this by commenting out "`#$customGlobalAsax.Document.Selection.Paste()`" to see if Global.asax.cs cleared and it only cleared if the `.ProjectItems` is left in.

Comment: I tried both '$customGlobalAsax = $project.ProjectItems | where { $_.Name -eq "Global.asax.cs" }' and '$customGlobalAsax = $project | where { $_.Name -eq "Global.asax.cs" }'. With both I lost the handle on the file. I checked to see if the content had made it to the clipboard, and it had not. The original line for its purpose seems to work fine.

Comment: Can you try this `$customGlobalAsax = ($project.ProjectItems | ForEach-Object { $_ } | where { $_.Name -eq "Global.asax.cs" })`. Just added a pair of brackets. I just realized there might be some flow control problem. It run `$customGlobalAsax = $project.ProjectItems` first. It only assign a variable and give no object to the next command in pipe line.